# Tomcat ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling [asyncPostProcess()] is not valid for a request with Async state [STARTED]

Tags: tomcat7, long-polling, cometd

in tried to get this simple demo running on tomcat 7.0.37:
https://github.com/cometd/cometd-tutorials/tree/master/client-hello

I changed the web.xml to support async call (cometD is used with long-polling).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cometd.annotation.AnnotationCometdServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transports</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>org.cometd.tutorials.ClientHelloService</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>continuation</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>continuation</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

If i press the button to send somehting to the server i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling [asyncPostProcess()] is not valid for a request with Async state [STARTED]
at org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine.asyncPostProcess(AsyncStateMachine.java:204)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.asyncPostProcess(AbstractProcessor.java:116)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:593)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Perhaps someone can bring light in this stack?

Comment: I now tried Version 7.0.40 after i read that some tomcat versions could have bugs with the async functioanlity, but i still get this error.

Comment: Remove the `ContinuationFilter`, it's not needed in a Servlet 3.0 container, and see if it makes a difference. Does it work using Jetty 7.6.11 instead of Tomcat ?

Comment: The same issue for me Tomcat 7.0.52 filter is set to `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` hey out there SO crowd - HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting true on all of your filters. See http://cometd.org/node/106

> The async-supported element should be specified for the CometD servlet and for all filters that may be executed before the CometD servlet such as the CrossOriginFilter.

I was getting this issue because I had one newly added filter that had nothing to do with cometd that was missing this tag. Adding the tag fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use frameworks like struts, take care of filters dynamically added by it, other than filters configured in web.xml.
http://blog.163.com/pilgrim_yang/blog/static/556314812014218977633/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55331) bug. It has been fixed in Tomcat 7.0.43.